# Problematic parsing of html table with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium webdriver with java to test a web application in my company and I face a very strange problem. The web application after logging in displays this table with the values as shown in the picture in the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0i_2gNTlx1Sek9EQVQ1ZlY1a0E/view?usp=sharing

I have wrote this code that parses the table with xpath because the table's rows and td cells are id-less.

```
               //Parsing the table.
               int increment = 0;
               int i = 0;

               for(increment=1; increment <= 16; increment++){ 
                 StringBuilder nsb = new StringBuilder("");
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

                for(i=1; i <= 6; i++){              

                    try {
                        WebElement f = wd.findElement((By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+increment+"]/td["+i+"]")));                                 
                        sb.append(f.getText().replaceAll("\\n", " ")).append(" ");                          
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ed) {           
                        ed.getSuppressed();
                    }       

                }                           

                      System.out.println(sb);                                       
              }             
            System.out.println();
```

The problem now is that when I print the values of each row sometimes and in random order i lose some of the values on the output as shown in the  picture i post below(for example if i re-run the program the second field in the second row called SAB will be missing).

Correct output is 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0i_2gNTlx1SQmFoZDd0UkgzVXM/view?usp=sharing

I tried instead of **getText** method the **getAttribute("textContent")** but i face the same random problem.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?
Sorry for the links but I didn't have any alternative to show you my problem..I can also post a random faulty output I got during testing if it's needed..

Comment: Give the html code of the web application.

Comment: That XPath is horrible! Do not use a `for` counter loops. Set up one loop where you iterate over `findElements(By.tagname('tr'))`, and an inner loop where iterate over `findElements(By.tagname('td'))`.

Answer (score 0):

One thought,
why did you add ?

```
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException ed) {           
                    ed.getSuppressed();
                }
```

Are you getting this exception if not catching?
**if yes**, then
might be your page or element is getting refreshed 
and when you are referring f on second line to getText() you may get StaleElementReferenceException, But as you are suppressing it your loop continues and **value is lost because of exception**.

you can try replacing

```
  WebElement f = wd.findElement((By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+increment+"]/td["+i+"]")));                                 
  sb.append(f.getText().replaceAll("\\n", " ")).append(" ");
```

with single statement

```
  sb.append(wd.findElement((By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+increment+"]/td["+i+"]"))).getText().replaceAll("\\n", " ")).append(" ");
```

Probably this will avoid staleElement Exception if issue is caused by it.

Comment: In order to avoid getting this exception had to switch to use **ExpectedCondition** class and not *thread.sleep()* in order to wait for a script to finish loading. After that i switched to **findElements()** and with an enhanced for loop i solved the problem with loosing values. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.